# Accessing View from ViewController

Tags: objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller

I created a ViewController in StoryBoard and linked it with the GamePanelViewController class.
Furthermore I linked the view of the ViewController with a second class called GamePanel which extends of UIView.

How can I access to the view which is created automatically by StoryBoard to perform some methods I implemented to the GamePanel class which is linked to the view by identity inspector?

GamePanel.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Plattform.h"

@interface GamePanel : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *plattforms;

- (void)initGamePanel;
- (void)drawPlattforms:(CGContextRef)gc;

@end
```

GamePanel.m:

```
#import "GamePanel.h"

@implementation GamePanel

@synthesize plattforms;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initGamePanel{
   self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.plattforms = [NSMutableArray new];
    // Initialization code
    for(int i = 0;i<8;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<6;j++){
            [self.plattforms addObject:[[Plattform alloc] initWithXCord:(14+j*37) andYCoord:(58+14+i*37)]];
            NSLog(@"Init");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have actually linked the viewController's `view` property with your custom view, then you can simply use `self.view` within you viewController to access it.

If you have just dragged a UIView onto your viewController in your storyboard (and not linked it to the viewController's view property), you will need to create an IBOutlet for it (control-drag from the view to your interface, and give it a name), then you can reference it with the name you give it e.g. `self.myView`.

Comment: In the Connection Inspector I can see that the view outlet is actually linked with the view called "GamePanel". But if I try to call the method "initGamePanel" from my ViewController I get following error message: [self.view initGamePanel]; - No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'initGamePanel'

Comment: You will need to cast self.view to your GamePanel class - `[(GamePanel *)self.view initGamePanel];`.

Comment: Now I get a very similar error message: No visible @interface for 'GamePanel' declares the selector 'initGamePanel' :/ I'm able to call the "initWithFrame" method but initGamePanel doesn't work -.-

Comment: Have you added the `initGamePanel` method declaration to GamePanel's public interface (.h file)?

Comment: This also fixed a problem I had where I had set up the pointers in each direction: to the viewController from the view and to the view from the viewController. Xcode accepted them, but when I built the app I got an error saying it did not recognise my custom classes. I declared the classes @class etc. as well as importing the headers - but it still would not build. The key was to cast the pointers to my custom classes when I set them exactly as Joe suggests.